# How is Philips TV Browser getting preview images for pages?

Tags: smart-tv

I want to provide my own preview image for page in Philips TV (NETTV models) browser.
It is displayed near page address in history.

How can I do it?

[image]
(image from [avforum](https://www.avforums.com/review/philips-smart-tv-system-2014-review.10396), obtained from google search)

Philips TV use Opera 11.6 as browser.
userAgent string is:

```
Opera/9.80 (Linux mips; U; HbbTV/1.1.1 (; Philips; ; ; ; ) CE-HTML/1.0 NETTV/4.0.2; en) Presto/2.10.250 Version/11.60
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly how the Philips TV browser works, but the most logical thing to try out first would be the `og:image` tag and see if the TV picks it up.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.png"/>
```

If not, then the TV is probably using some screen capture library. You could try this workaround to get the desired behaviour:

First, find out your TV's user agent. For example, browse to http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ from your TV.

Then on your page, create a small script that checks the user agent, and if it's the TV, show your preview picture as an overlay for a few seconds.

Hopefully the TV will take a screenshot of the initial render of the page, and then your TV splash will show.

```js
function hideSplash() {
  document.getElementById("tv-splash").style.display = "none";
}

// Remove '|Mozilla' when development is ready 
if (/Philips|Mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  setTimeout(hideSplash, 2000);
} else {
  hideSplash();
}
```

```css
#tv-splash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f00 url(http://i.imgur.com/IonCAf7.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="tv-splash"></div>
<h1>My website</h1>
```

Comment: Ok, as you can see the user agent contains the word "Philips" so you can probably use it to identify when the TV is looking at your page.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have time to check it. I will have device to check only on next week. However bounty is expires tomorrow,  so i will award it to you.